# Getting "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content in" Android

Tags: android, exception

I am getting Unknown URL exception "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://com.abcd/metertable" in my below android code, What could be reason for it. Can someone please help, Thanks in advance :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://com.abcd/table
at android.content.ContentResolver.delete(ContentResolver.java:955)
at com.abcd.Class.mymethod(Class.java:536)
at com.abcd.Class.access$8(Class.java:530)
at com.abcd.Class$MeterTask.onPostExecute(Class.java:290)
at com.abcd.Class$MeterTask.onPostExecute(Class.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4849)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Provider :

```
<provider android:name="com.abcd.meters.Class2"
              android:authorities="com.abcd.myclass">
</provider>
```

Code :

```
private void mymethod()
    {
        ContentResolver crol = context.getContentResolver();
        int rows = crol.delete(MyClass.CONTENT_URI, MyClass.MARK_FOR_DELETE + "=1", null);
        Log.d(TAG, rows + " rows deleted");
        // Count records to upload

    }
```

URI :

```
public static final String PACKAGE = "com.abcd";
public static final String TABLE = "table";
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://"+ PACKAGE + "/" + TABLE);
```

Answer (score 3):

`android:authorities` should not be the class you define, but the `uri`authorities. it should be like this:

```
<provider android:name="com.abcd.meters.myclass"
          android:authorities="com.abcd">
</provider>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error says that you are trying to access `content://com.abcd/metertable`, where the "authority" is "`com.abcd`".

The AndroidManifest provider tag has only defined the authority of "`com.abcd.myclass`".

If you match those, then the provider will work.

Comment: thanks bro :) had been struggling with the same issue for more than 2 hrs..finally solved :)